# Как создать обработчик (listener) для вызова экранной клавиатуры?

Tags: android, java

Нужно, чтобы при появлении экранной клавиатуры (при нажатии на `EditText`) выполнялся один код, а при скрытии - другой. При создании `activity` клавиатура скрыта.

Вариант с `OnFocusChangeListener` не прокатывает, так как `EditText` - единственное поле на `activity` и он всегда в фокусе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае отловить собственно появление или исчезновение IME нереально. Можно привязаться к изменению размеров окна, но опять же это может работать по разному для разных IME. Потому остается только отлавливать клики и нажатия.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогли оба ответа, так и сделал. Просто надеялся, что есть более элегантное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Существует довольно простое и более/менее элегантное [решение](https://felhr85.net/2014/05/04/catch-soft-keyboard-showhidden-events-in-android/), которое работает для меня. 
Возможно как-то поможет будущим "искателям приключений" =)

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. 
Попробуйте `setOnTouchListener`.